# Move values from one column to another column

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible using VBA to move values from ColumnC to ColumnB, ColumnD to ColumnC, and etc.?

After I import the text file from Excel and format it to text to column some of the data is not in the correct column.

For example,

```
ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD
1    | Sam1 | ABC  | 111
2    | Sam2 | DEF  | 222
3    | Sam3 | 101  | 333
4    | Sam4 | ABC  | 444
```

In this example, ColumnC with value of "ABC" and "DEF" is part of ColumnB. It is placed in ColumnC after I format it to text to column.
Also the value from ColumnD, should be in the ColumnC.

Comment: `Range("B2").Insert Shift:=xlToRight` will insert a cell in B2 and shift everything along by one cell.

Comment: So the issue is that there was a single column in your source data which was split into columns B and C when you imported it?

Comment: @jsheeran, yes, it was split into Columns B and C after I imported the data.. and, the other values was moved to the next column.

Comment: It might be easier to correct the data before the import or before the text to columns.  Think that's what @jSheeran is getting at one of those [XY](http://xyproblem.info/) problem thingies.

Comment: We/user don't have the rights to modify the data coming from the customer.

Comment: An option might be to use a formula to concatenate B and C together, for example `=B2&C2`. Then you can copy that and paste it as values into column B, and delete C.

Answer (score 1):

The code below will insert a blank cell in col3 when the value is a number, it will then combine the values from col2 and col3, and then delete col3.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, lRow As Long, i As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

With ws
    For x = 1 To lRow
        If IsNumeric(.Cells(x, 3).Value) Then
            .Cells(x, 3).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        End If

        .Cells(x, 2).Value = .Cells(x, 2).Value & " " & .Cells(x, 3).Value
    Next x

    .Columns(3).Delete
End With
End Sub
```